# Excel Macro attaching PDF file and sending email Lotus Notes

Tags: vba, excel, lotus

I'm trying to send an email attaching a PDF file using Lotus Notes.

I've been looking for the answer during the last weeks, I've found a lot of code to do it using Outlook and many webmails, but all I've find that works using Lotus Notes is the following code:

```
Sub Enviar_Correo()

ActiveWorkbook.SendMail _
Recipients:=" xxx@yyyy.com", _
Subject:= "Envío de prueba"

End Sub
```

It open a new mail, with the correct destination, subject and body. But it attach the current workbook (I need a PDF file hosted in my computer), and it doesn't send the email.

I know that is not an easy question but, could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

What is the link between sending your email and excel? If you want to send an email with an attachment, there are many ways like:

C# samples:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9d1a22d4-4355-455a-8f57-072bb2a5d7c0/how-to-send-email-with-multiple-attachments-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral
- [Sending email with attachments from C#, attachments arrive as Part 1.2 in Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde)

If you need to customize the email before sending (with user interface), it's a different way. You should add more information about your needs:

- input
- content
- special needs...