# C# Mail pdf attachment utf-8

Tags: c#, email, pdf, utf-8, erp

In my application, i send mails to managers from program automatically. Normally it works good, but when i use program on another computer, it sends mail automatically but file type is not PDF. File type is File and name of pdf is `=utf-8BQU5HT1JBIEhBTEkgQS7Fni4gR8OcTkzD`. I also checked source codes. But I couldn't understand what is wrong with that. Any idea what to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to fill the ContentDisposition, example is here:
[Sending email with attachments from C#, attachments arrive as Part 1.2 in Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde)

Maybe, in the code you can change the MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet to MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf

I hope, this helps!