# Sending e-mail with attachment C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, email, sendmail, smtpclient

I need to send email message with attachment. I'm using below code:

```
MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("adrFrom", "adrTo", "header", "body");

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("hostName", 25);
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("accountName", "password");

Attachment atch = new Attachment(filePath, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

atch.Name = "FileName.docx";

msg.Attachments.Add(atch);

client.Send(msg);
```

Message is received, and attachment is there too, but file name looks like ' =?utf-8?B?dXRHRDBZTFJnOUdBMFlzZzBKelF1TkNoPz0NCiA9P3V0Zi04P0I/TG1S?=\', also there is no extension(.docx) and file content looks like it's in the Base64 encoding. 
How can I send e-mail message with .docx file saving it extension and name?

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/a/2828438/20126

Comment: You specify `Application.Octet` as your content type (which is binary) and the default `TransferEncoding` is set to `base64`. That's why you're seeing a base64 string.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov If I don't use Application.Octet problem is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have found a solution**

The problem was in Russian letters in the file name. Without it everything works fine.

Comment: @MoslemBenDhaou yes, thats also solved by installing microsoft patch. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2402064

Answer (score 1):

Add **Contentype** to your Attachment

```
System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType();
contentType.MediaType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
contentType.Name = "test.docx";
msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("I:/files/test.docx"), contentType);
```

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Ahmedabad ka hoke esa karta hai hahah