# How to send an email with excel sheet attachment in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My requirement is to send an email with excel sheet attachment with a specific time in ASP.NET MVC4.
That means i have an web based application which is develop on ASP.NET(MVC4)razor with ADO.NET so my requirement is to fetch all entry from database and convert to excel sheet then send every days record on every morning at 06:00AM what can do

Comment: Any One is worked on that module please provide me a technology that can send this?????????????...........

Comment: try this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde

Answer (score 0):

Folowing step maybe help you:

Create a windows service to do this module

- In windows service: query your database and fetch them to excel file
- Save your excel file
- Use @Venkata Tata link to send email [Sending email with attachments from C#, attachments arrive as Part 1.2 in Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde)

*User Timer object in Windows service of .NET to set time 6:00am to do all step everyday.

ASP.NET(MVC4) can't do your module.