# Empty file when sending an email with Attachment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, email-attachments

I'm trying to send an emil with Attachment using Postal framework for MVC.

I can send e-mails with Postal without problem, however, when I try send an e-mail with attachment, the files goes empty.

Here is my code:

```
dynamic emailNovoOrcamento = new Email("OrcamentosServicos/NotificaNovoOrcamento");
emailNovoOrcamento.To = usuario.UsuEmail;
emailNovoOrcamento.From = "no-reply@servicili.com";
emailNovoOrcamento.Subject = "Test...";

ContentType conteudo = new ContentType();
conteudo.MediaType = MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg;
conteudo.Name = "userPhoto.jpg";

Attachment imagemDestinatario = new Attachment(new getUserPhotoStream(usuario), conteudo);
emailNovoOrcamento.Attachments.Add(imagemDestinatario);
emailNovoOrcamento.Send();
```

`getUserPhotoStream` is a method that converts a `byte[]` to a `Stream`:

```
public MemoryStream getUserPhotoStream(byte[] photo)
{
    MemoryStream imagemStream = new MemoryStream();
    Image imagem;
    MemoryStream imagemUsuarioStream = new MemoryStream(photo);

        imagem = Image.FromStream(imagemUsuarioStream);
        imagem.Save(imagemStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        return imagemStream;
    }
}
```

When I send it via Email, the file size is 0kb.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the position of the stream to 0 before using it:

```
// ...
imagem.Save(imagemStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
imagemStream.Position = 0;
return imagemStream;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sending email with attachments from C#, attachments arrive as Part 1.2 in Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde)

See this, It may give some insight. I did something like you but from here.