# Timer and thread lock

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a file, to which data is saved a  all the time.. 
I have a timer which runs once every 4 second
My process looks like:
File x.txt is open all the time.
after 4 sec I want to stop the process and send this file by email.
I want to repeat above steps all the time.

my code:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
        {
            wrtiteToFile.Suspend();

            SendEmail();
            wrtiteToFile.Resume();

        };

  static void SendEmail()
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        NetworkCredential basicCredential =
            new NetworkCredential("", "");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("");
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.Port = ;
        smtpClient.Host = "";
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;


        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "";
        //Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "";
        message.To.Add("");
        message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Application.StartupPath + @"\log.txt"));


        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
```

> The process cannot access the file 'C:\log.txt' because it is being used by another process.
>   It's not working. What is the best manner in which I can do this? I tried lock but it doesn't work too.
>   I must use .net framework 2.0

Comment: How are you opening your file, and whats in your sendemail function

Comment: @Stefan If it is, it is not a very a good one. Just spam sending an email will likely fail to spam someones inbox because of spam filters and such.

Comment: I think, the program which sends the mail is using your `x.txt`. Please share `SendEmail()`

Comment: @Jacobr365: touché ;-)

Comment: Explicitly filling in the ContentDisposition may help you. Look here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't disposing your resources. This way it is unsure when the resources (file locks) are released.

You should fix it with proper disposing of the resources. 
(Disclaimer, I haven't checked this)

```
static void SendEmail()
{
    using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
    using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
    using (Attachment attachment = new Attachment(Application.StartupPath + @"\log.txt"))
    {
        NetworkCredential basicCredential =
            new NetworkCredential("", "");

        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("");
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.Port = "";
        smtpClient.Host = "";
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "";
        //Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "";
        message.To.Add("");
        message.Attachments.Add(attachment);


        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}
```

The `using` statement will implicit call the `Dispose` method of the disposables, and hence, releasing file handles and other kind of connections.

Answer (score 0):

Your SendMail method block file. Simplest way fix :)

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(4000);
    timer.Enabled = true;
    timer.Elapsed += (object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        wrtiteToFile.Suspend();
        SendEmail();
        wrtiteToFile.Resume();
        timer.Enabled = true;

    };
```