# Plain Text not showing when sending an email with an attached file in C#

Tags: c#

When I send an html email with an attached file, Plain Text on Thunderbird doesn't show anything, especially when an attached file is docx, pdf, or etc. txt file was okay when I tested though.

It works well if I don't attach any files, Thunderbird correctly shows Html Text and Plain Text if I switch its view setting.

```
using(var mail = new MailMessage()){
    // ...omit
    var alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<h1>TEST</h1>", Encoding, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
    alternateView.TransferEncoding = TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
    mail.AlternateViews.Add(alternateView);

    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("path to a file"));
    // ...omit
}
```

I tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/2828438/366049 but no luck.

--EDITED--
As Caius Jard suggested, I tried the following and the results are below.

- setting it as the main body + the HTML as an alternateview
  **It works, but this means I have to prepare plain text and html text. If I don't attach any files, Thunderbird shows plain text which is from html text removing tags. I want this behavior all the time since input text is made by our users. Otherwise I need to retrieve plain text from html.**
- setting both the text and the HTML as alternate views, no main body
  **Both Plain Text and Html Text settings in Thunderbird show the text alternate view.**
- setting the text as both the main body and a text alternateview as well as having an HTML alternateview
  **Thunderbird shows the text alternate view even if I switch its view setting.**

According to these experiments, a plain alternate view is superior than an html alternate view and a main body.

Comment: Did You try MINE type?

Comment: I do set MIME type on the alternateView in the code above.

Comment: How does one CRAFT a MINE type? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question doesn't seem to contain example code that demonstrates how you set the plaintext, try

- setting it as the main body + the HTML as an alternateview
- setting both the text and the HTML as alternate views, no main body
- setting the text as both the main body and a text alternateview as well as having an HTML alternateview

I'd be interested to know which of these works out for thunderbird..

Comment: this should be a comment, not answer

Comment: This is not a direct answer, but I decided to put a message on a mail body like saying "Please change the view setting to the html view", and it should work for now.