# Is there any method In .net MVC to export database date in file not in local machine and send as file attachment with email.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Here is My Export code.

```
        public void ExportCSV_Employee(HttpPostedFileBase file )
          {
        var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        var list = _context.ProductItems.ToList();
        
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\t{12}\t{13}\t{14}\t{15}\t{16}\t{17}\t{18}\t{19}\t{20}\t{21}\t{22}\t{23}\t{24}\t{25}\r", item.ScanCode, item.Name, item.UnitRetail, item.UnitCost, item.DeptName, item.PriceGroup, item.ProductCode, item.Pcode, item.StateTax, item.MaxQty, item.Modified, item.AllowFoodStamps, item.LocalTax, item.Crv, item.MinAge, item.AllowDirectDept, item.IsNegative, item.DeptType, item.ItemCategoryId, item.ProductSubCategory, item.AllowFractionDept, item.BuyDown, item.UpcType, item.OverRide, item.PkgSize, item.Discount);
        }


      //mail method to send mail

        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Port = 587;   
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com" , "password");  
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

        //recipient address
        mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@gmail.com"));
```

}

in this way, my mail sending work but I want to attach the date from my database as a start retrieving through StringBuilder. How can I attach my data as a file attachment with email?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending email with attachments from C#, attachments arrive as Part 1.2 in Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825950/sending-email-with-attachments-from-c-attachments-arrive-as-part-1-2-in-thunde)

Comment: No. Your link receives the file from the local PC but I want to attach the file from the direct database and send it by email.

Comment: I do not see much difference there. All you need is to get the bytes from the database. I am posting an answer with sample codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
var list = _context.ProductItems.ToList();
            
foreach (var item in list)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\t{12}\t{13}\t{14}\t{15}\t{16}\t{17}\t{18}\t{19}\t{20}\t{21}\t{22}\t{23}\t{24}\t{25}\r", item.ScanCode, item.Name, item.UnitRetail, item.UnitCost, item.DeptName, item.PriceGroup, item.ProductCode, item.Pcode, item.StateTax, item.MaxQty, item.Modified, item.AllowFoodStamps, item.LocalTax, item.Crv, item.MinAge, item.AllowDirectDept, item.IsNegative, item.DeptType, item.ItemCategoryId, item.ProductSubCategory, item.AllowFractionDept, item.BuyDown, item.UpcType, item.OverRide, item.PkgSize, item.Discount);
}
```

//Create a virtual file in memory

```
byte[] bytes = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
  TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);
  tw.Write(sb.Tostring());
  tw.Flush();
  ms.Position = 0;
  bytes = ms.ToArray();
}
```

//Create Attachment

```
Attachment att = new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), name);
```

//mail method to send mail

```
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Port = 587;   
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com" , "password");  
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    //recipient address
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@gmail.com"));
```

//Add the attachment to the mail message

```
mail.Attachments.Add(data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how can we send this as the File attachment with an email in the above email sending code.

Comment: Rahatur answer very helps full. Thanks

Comment: @NumanCS I have updated the codes to show how to attach the file. Hope that helps. Font forget to up vote the answer if it worked for you :)

Answer (score 0):

After spending some time I figure out the solution for this problem first save data in a Memorystream and then pass it to the email attachment method.

```
     {
      public void ExportCSV_Employee(HttpPostedFileBase file )
         {
         var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
          var list = _context.ProductItems.ToList();
        
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\t{7}\t{8}\t{9}\t{10}\t{11}\t{12}\t{13}\t{14}\t{15}\t{16}\t{17}\t{18}\t{19}\t{20}\t{21}\t{22}\t{23}\t{24}\t{25}\r", item.ScanCode, item.Name, item.UnitRetail, item.UnitCost, item.DeptName, item.PriceGroup, item.ProductCode, item.Pcode, item.StateTax, item.MaxQty, item.Modified, item.AllowFoodStamps, item.LocalTax, item.Crv, item.MinAge, item.AllowDirectDept, item.IsNegative, item.DeptType, item.ItemCategoryId, item.ProductSubCategory, item.AllowFractionDept, item.BuyDown, item.UpcType, item.OverRide, item.PkgSize, item.Discount);
        }
        //Storing data in virtual memory and then pass to email attachment  

        var myString = sb.ToString();
        var myByteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myString);
        var ms = new MemoryStream(myByteArray);


    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mymail@gmail.com");

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Port = 587;   
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network; 
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false; 
    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mymail@gmail.com" , "password");  
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    //recipient address
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("receiver@gmail.com"));
    string Fname = "PriceBook.dat";
        
        if ( ms!= null)
        {
            string fileName = Fname;
            
            mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, "fileName.dat", "text/dat"));
        };
       smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

}